# What happen when I set Quiet to true in Amazon S3 for anabling Quiet Mode in deleteObjects() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm working with Amazon S3 in Node.js and I want to delete one or more files from a bucket. I want to know what happen when I set Quiet parameter to true.

```
var params = {
  Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Delete: { /* required */
    Objects: [ /* required */
      {
        Key: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
        VersionId: 'STRING_VALUE'
      },
      /* more items */
    ],
    Quiet: true || false
  },
  MFA: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
s3.deleteObjects(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As from Amazon Docs:
**Quiet Mode:**

> Toggles between Quiet and Verbose mode for the operation. If set to
>   true (Quiet mode), the response includes only those keys for objects
>   on which the delete operation failed.